# how to check items of one list in another in python with loops

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

I want to check for a certain condition list and then print it
suppose i want to check items of a in b

I want to check for values of list "a" in list "b" so i used this code

```
   a=[1,2]
   b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,]
   c=[]
   for i in a:   
      for j in b:
           if i!=j:
           c.append(j)
```

but i am getting infinite loop when i run this code code please help me.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify a bit about what is a _condition list_ and double-check if your indentation is correct. Also, do you see any output from the "infinite loop"?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what behavior you would like to implement, but I guess you want to filter out elements in `b` that appear in `a`. If so, you can do this:

```py
a = [1, 2]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
c = []
for i in b:
    if not i in a:
        c.append(i)
print(c)
```

The result:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**If you want to recover
identical elements in each list then try this code:**

c = []


def list_contains(a, b):
    for x in a:
        for y in b:
            if x == y:
                c.append(x)
                continue
    return c


a = [1, 2]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ]
print(list_contains(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use some list comprehension!

I'll rename your lists:

```py
list_a = [1, 2]
list_b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So you want a list of everything in `list_b`...

```py
result = [elem for elem in list_b] # (this just copies the list)
```

...where the element is also in `list_a`:

```py
result = [elem for elem in list_b if elem in list_a]
```

...where the element is **not** in `list_a`:

```py
result = [elem for elem in list_b if elem not in list_a]
```

Alternatively, make a function and use `filter`:

```py
def keep_b_if(b_elem):
    return b_elem in list_a
    # or
    return b_elem not in list_a

result = filter(keep_b_if, list_b)
```

Also, if `a` is just a collection of values to preserve/lose from `b`, it can be a `set` instead of a `list`:

```py
forbidden = {1, 2}
...
if elem not in forbidden:
    ...
```